# Link userform textbox to textbox on excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I'd like to input into my Userform textbox and see that value on my excel textbox. This is what I have been trying to use.

Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("TextBox 1").Value = TextBox1.Value

Comment: Where are you putting your code?  Is it in the click event of a button on the form.  Is the code executing?  Do you get an error?

Answer (score 0):

From the code provided it looks like you are using the shape text box and not the ActiveX control text box.  For the shape you would need something similar to the below:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Shapes("TextBox 1").TextFrame.Characters.Text = "Your Text Value"
```

You can replace "Your Text Value" with a value contained in a string variable or with the value of a form text box.